# Parallel execution in cx-oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have recently joined a new company and am new to python (their preferred scripting language) and have been working with cx_oracle to create some ETL processes.  The scripts I have built so far have been single-threaded jobs that select the subset of columns I need from an Oracle source DB and write the output to a named pipe where an external process is waiting to read that data and insert it into the target.

This has worked fine until I get to some tables that are in the 500 million -2 billion row range.  The job still works, but it is taking many hours to complete.  These large source tables are partitioned so I have been trying to research ways to coordinate parallel reads of different partitions so I can get two or more threads working concurrently, each writing to a separate named pipe.

Is there an elegant way in cx-oracle to handle multiple threads reading from different partitions of the same table?

Here's my current (simple) code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

# connect via SQL*Net string or by each segment in a separate argument
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/password@TNS")


csv.register_dialect('pipe_delimited', escapechar='\\' delimiter='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

cursor = connection.cursor()
f = open("<path_to_named_pipe>", "w")

writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='pipe_delimited', lineterminator="\n")
r = cursor.execute("""SELECT <column_list> from <SOURCE_TABLE>""")
for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Some of my source tables have over 1000 partitions so hard-coding the partition names in isn't the preferred option.  I have been thinking about setting up arrays of partition names and iterating through them, but if folks have other ideas I'd love to hear them.

Comment: In a related question, there are several options for parallel execution of tasks in python.  My problem involves I/O-heavy tasks that do not need to pass data back and forth between them.  Would **threaded**, **multiprocess**, **subprocess** or something else be most appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure that *cx_Oracle* is thread-safe. Since it implements the [Python DB API Spec v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), all you need to do is check the `threadsafety` module global. 
Values `2` or `3` mean that you can open multiple connections to the DB and run multiple queries at the same time. The best way to do this is to use the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module, which is pretty easy to use. [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) is a short and sweet article on how to get started with it.

Of course, there are no guarantees that pipelining your queries will result in a significant performance gains (DB engine, I/O, etc. reasons) but it's definitely worth the try. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I know cx_Oracle has threadsafety of 2.  It can be done... just need to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: python-oracledb (the [renamed, new version of cx_Oracle](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)) now has asyncio support, see https://medium.com/@cjones-oracle/concurrent-python-programming-with-python-oracledb-and-asyncio-d745cbc3a77f